Does there exist a planar/2D version of gauss's method of orbit determination?
I have been looking into orbit determination methods for some projects i was working on, specifically those where the only observational data is azimuth and elevation. Naturally Gauss's method came up often. But one of the requirements of gauss's method is that the observations can't be planar. In that case there is a divide-by-zero error during the algorithm (step 5 of Wikipedia's formulation, $D_0$ is the scalar triple product of the observations and thus zero when they are planar).
This means that in the rare case where both the observer and the object are in the same plane, determination is impossible with that method. This also means that reversing the method, I.e. finding the orbit of the observer based on the elevation/azimuth to the parent body is impossible.
So my question is if there is a fix to Gauss's method to make it work in a planar scenario? Or an alternative method that can do the same thing?
Edit: I am specifically looking for an alternative to gauss's function that specifically works with three planar observations. Not just an orbit fitter (that's what gauss is for already)

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. This is my fault. Do you mean to turn a 3-D field into a 2-D field? As for gravitation, if you use field lines, where the n number of field lines is given by the holographic principle (e.g. the binary entropy), and this number is conserved, then obviously the interaction gets stronger along the plane, and weaker elsewhere. If the field is self-interacting, then the strength climbs by a factor of c as well.

This is not about fields, it's about keplerian orbits. As in, I observed the asteroid Ceres over 9 days, I want to find it's orbit so I can predict where it is in the future.

Sorry for the confusion. The field line solution produces the Newtonian gravitational field, where the spatial dimension count is D = 3, and falloff is like $1/r^2$. Are you asking about anisotropic graviton emitters, where D = 2, falloff of $1/r$?

OK, your main objective is to fit an ellipse onto some sample points? What code have you tried so far? Which language are you using?

Alright. I've read that the Gaussian method produces the coefficients for the ellipse equation, where the ellipse is a level set.

Check ChatGPT for 'gauss method ellipse C++'.

Also, do you know about Marching Squares?
